# how to export a Spring Boot Gradle project in Eclips IDE?

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I have one Spring Boot gradle project and Now, When I click on Export Project then my project is not reflecting. Can anyone help me with the steps to export Spring Boot gradle project?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you're using the built-in Eclipse exporter to generate jar, which only includes the target files actually produced in that project. In order to have a "fat" (standalone executable) jar, you need to use the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to "repackage" the jar.

Once the spring-boot plugin has been applied to your project it will automatically attempt to rewrite archives to make them executable using the `bootRepackage`  task. You should configure your project to build a jar or war (as appropriate) in the usual way.

The main class that you want to launch can either be specified using a configuration option, or by adding a Main-Class attribute to the manifest. If you don’t specify a main class the plugin will search for a class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.

Check [Section 67.6, “Repackage configuration”](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration) for a full list of configuration options.

To build and run a project artifact, you can type the following:

```
$ gradle build
$ java -jar build/libs/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: You should be using the `spring-boot` plugin and not manually create a jar. Spring Boot requires a specific format of the jar which isn't honored when using either one of these solutions.

Comment: @M.Deinum Your are right, my solution was not spring specific. I fixed it.

Comment: @RAVIRK You can select my solution as an answer with a check mark on the left side of the answer, if it works for you.

Comment: @RAVIRK Can I ask you, do it again? Because the answer is not set for this question. Thanks

Comment: Yep, surething.